# How to detect corrupt video?

Tags: ffmpeg

Hope you're well.

I've devised a simple way to discover corrupt video files with FFmpeg which seems to work pretty well:

```
# detect corrupt video file
## single file

ffmpeg -loglevel error -i [url] -map 0:a -f null -

ffmpeg
-loglevel error
-i [url] // input url
-map 0:a // select audio stream of first file (audio enough to detect video corruption)
-f null // file format output
- // output

## multiple file/directory

find [url] -iname "*" -print -exec ffmpeg -loglevel error -i {} -map 0:a -f null - &> error.log \;

find
[url]
-iname "*"
-print // file name for output reference
-exec
ffmpeg
-loglevel error
-i {} // input url (i.e. -exec argument)
-map 0:a // select audio stream of first file
-f null // file format output
- // output
&> error.log \;
```

Since I don't really know what constitutes an error in FFmpeg land (e.g. dropped/missing frames, corrupted frames [image and/or audio]) I wonder if there is a more efficient/specific solution (e.g. options) or whether anyone would be kind enough to elaborate on how FFmpeg generates errors?

If you have any issues (e.g. questions/queries) then I'll happy to help you.

Yours hopefully